# Problem with portrait orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

```
 -(void)search:(id)sender {

    if (([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)||([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
        [self landscapeTextField];
    }

        else if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {    
            [self portraitSearchTextField];
    }
    }
```

I am calling this function when my application button click.

when i am in portrait mode  `[self portraitSearchTextField]` is not calling

I checked in debug mode.

when i replace `else if` with `else [self portraitSearchTextField];` its working

but My current device in portrait mode while application loaded...  Why this condition is not executed. can any one help me out.

@thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using the UIInterfaceOrientation methods? E.g.: `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)` to test if the current interface is in landscape mode, there's also a method to check if the interface is in portrait mode.

Comment: no ... can you redirect to related example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    -(void)search:(id)sender {

    if (([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)||([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
            [self landscapeTextField];
    }

    else { 
        if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {    
            [self portraitSearchTextField];
        }
    }
}
```